# aws javascript sdk registerThing template body does not accept valid json string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am passing template json to the registerThing function as shown in below code part.

```
const templateJson = {"Parameters":{"Attr1":{"Type": "String"},"Attr2": {"Type": "String"},"AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id":{"Type": "String"}},"Resources":{"certificate":{"Properties": {"CertificateId":{"Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"},"Status": "Active"},"Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate"},"policy":{"Properties": {"PolicyDocument": "<<Inline olicy document>>"},"Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy"},"thing": {"OverrideSettings":{"AttributePayload": "MERGE","ThingGroups": "DO_NOTHING","ThingTypeName": "REPLACE"},"Properties":{"AttributePayload":{},"ThingGroups":["mygroup"],"ThingName": {"Ref": "SerialNumber"},"ThingTypeName": "testname"},"Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing"}},"DeviceConfiguration":{}};

const provisionTemplateBody = JSON.stringify(templateJson);
```

And then using this to construct function parameters as

```
 var paramsRegisterThing = {
        templateBody: provisionTemplateBody,
        parameters: provisioningTemplateParams
    };
```

When calling registerThing with this, I get exception as below

```
"errorType": "InvalidRequestException",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid registration template. Template format error: unsupported type or structure...
```

I have already added JSON.stringify as suggested in some other questions here on stackoverflow, but it does not help.

How can I make this work?
Or is there any other way to pass template name or ARN instead of body to register thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I noticed:

- Remove empty block of `DeviceConfiguration`
- There is Ref to `SerialNumber` , which is missing in Parameter block.
- You have two other attributes Attr1 & Attr2 in parameters which are not actually used in Resources block.

If both template and parameters are two Javascript objects. templateBody should be a sting and parameters should be key-value map.

```
 iot.registerThing(
      {
        templateBody: JSON.stringify(template1),
        parameters: parms,
      },
      function (err, data) {}
 )
```

Comment: Point 2 & 3 in this answer are because of my mistake while trying to replace original data before posting it here. Removing empty DeviceConfiguration made it work.